# Java connect to a remote desktop which resides in a different network

Tags: java, remote-desktop

I have to access the Oracle DB which resides in a different network. I have remote desktop access to a box which is connected to the DB network and I can access the DB through that remote desktop ..Is there a way I can write a Java program which connects to the remote desktop, executes the query and retrieve the value.

Comment: Sure there's a way, check out http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/ for a good library to remote desktop through java, once you're in, use the Runtime.exec() command to open up a script on that machine which takes in a string parameter, where that string would be your sql query. That being said, I feel like opening an ssh tunnel to that computer through java would be a simpler task since you don't need the GUI elements associated with remote desktop. It depends on how the firewall on both ends is set up

Comment: Thanks Wills!!!Do you know the best api for doing this ssh tunnel_ I googled and found this jsch, , a Java an implementation of SSH2. Not sure if there are better apis

Comment: hmm, I've never tried to actually run an ssh session programmatically, if you're only concerned about running it off of one environment that you have control to custom configure like you prefer, it might be possible to cheat your way around a true ssh library and just Runtime.exec() either the ssh command explicitly (making sure you have ssh on the path so you can run it on the command line through something like cygwin or what have you), or run a script that has all of the authentication necessary. It all really depends on how nice and how expandable you need it to be :)